# jquery. If window size <= certain value, then start jquery. But upon certain conditions jquery executes if screen > than certain value

Tags: jquery, css

Html

```
<div id="currentMedia">gggggggggg</div>
```

Then css

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
#currentMedia {
width: 480px;
}
}

@media all and (min-width: 481px) {
#currentMedia {
width: 481px;
}
}
```

If screen size is less than 481 px, then div width set 480px, else div width set 481px.

Then jquery that executes on page load and screen resize

```
var adjust_size = function() {

if (parseInt($("#currentMedia").css("width"), 10) <= 480) {

$(document).on('click', '.mnav-ul-li a', function(){
alert( 'clicked1 ' );
});

}

};//var adjust_size = function() {
adjust_size();
$(window).resize(adjust_size);
```

And html

```
<ul>
<li class="mnav-ul-li"><a href="#gg">Option 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

For example, screen width is 400px. Click on `Option 3`, executes `$(document).on('click', '.mnav-ul-li a', function(){`. So far ok.

But resize screen so that width is more than 480px. And click on `Option 3`. And again executes `$(document).on('click', '.mnav-ul-li a', function(){`. Why? It is inside `if (parseInt($("#currentMedia").css("width"), 10) <= 480) {` Must not execute.

What need to correct to get `$(document).on('click', '.mnav-ul-li a', function(){` execute only if screen size is less than 481px?

Here placed live example http://jsfiddle.net/kff6yhoc/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the condition is not inside the click event handler, its on the resize. What that means is that each time `adjust_size` is called when the width is <= 480, you register for the click event (you probably do that many many times). Then when the width grows above 480, you're no longer *registering*, but the event handler is still registered.

The solution is to move the `if` statement inside the click event handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mnav-ul-li a', function(){
   if (parseInt($("#currentMedia").css("width"), 10) <= 480)
      alert( 'clicked1 ' );
});
```

Comment: modified code http://jsfiddle.net/kff6yhoc/18/ Is it possible "unregister" for the click if screen width > 480px? Imagine, page load, screen width 400px. Registered for the click. Resize screen to 600px. Then again resize to 400px. In such case jquery executes 2 times (see 2 alerts)

Comment: Placed `$('.mnav-ul-li a').click(function() { return false; });` at the end of `if`. But it removes click even and on future resize >=480px on click does not execute....

Comment: Your code still registers many many times. That's pointless. Is there any reason for you to register / unregister as a reaction to resize? Why not register only 1 time (exactly as my code sample), and ignore the resize event completely? (P.S. if you _really_ have to unregister, [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) is the way to do it)

Comment: I use all this for navigation drop down menu. If narrow screen then expand sub categories on click. If wider screen, then expand on mouse over... As understand the function must place outside resize function? Yes http://jsfiddle.net/kff6yhoc/20/ resize function for this aim appears unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

> Please try this it will help.... eveytime you click on option 3 it will check window size ... and dowhat you want to do if size is less than 480

```
$(document).on('click', '.mnav-ul-li a', function(){
  if(CheckWindowSize())
  {
      alert("working...");
  }
    else
    {
        alert("width is less");
    }
});
function CheckWindowSize()
{
    if($(window).width() >= 480)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {   return false;
    }
}
```